# Why shouldn’t you be too concerned that Dropbox will decrypt your data if they receive a court order?

Tags: discussion, podcast

For those of us who don't listen to podcasts, can someone retell why Joel and/or Jeff don't worry about Dropbox decrypting your data ([podcast 88](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/podcast-88/))?

Comment: Sounds like an on-topic example for [Privacy.se](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31293/privacy)! (Now curious too.)

Comment: See, *this* is why the transcripts were useful... (And for all the good folks flagging this as OT - where are folks *supposed* to ask questions about the podcast, if not here?)

Comment: And I learned something else: we have an [off-topic tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic)?

Comment: The blog has a comments section.  This isn't about the sites.

Comment: @Arjan: yeah, but... It's not a *meta-meta-tag*

Comment: I suggest listening to the podcast, but that could just be me. Additionally, this would be a great content on any of a dozen SE sites, to be sure!